# Use Ember components with Require.js

Tags: ember.js, requirejs

Is it possible to use Ember Components without ember-cli, and load them dynamically with require.js?

We have to use require.js for legacy reasons and would eventually migrate from it, but we need some time. Currently we use Ember Views with require.js just fine, can't I can't figure out how to switch them to controllers.

Comment: you will be better off using `ember-cli ` and load your legacy code with https://github.com/ef4/ember-browserify

Comment: I know, and we are on the way there, but it won't happen overnight (it's a BIG project), hence the question.

Comment: Ember without `ember-cli`, no problem, it will work out of the box (you'll have to look at older documentation as the new one assumes you're using ember-cli). Loading with require.js? If you want to load all at once as a single require call, doable, but if you want to load components individually I doubt it can be done without a large amount of work.

Comment: Yes, we don't load all at once, as we have some configurable dynamic parts. We almost got legacy views to work for now (there are some nasty bugs with them), migrating to ember-cli soonish.
Can you provide this as an answer so I could accept it?